# Finding Median value given a tuple (value, frequency) in O(n) worst case time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, sorting, selection-problem

> An accountant in a big firm would like to find the median of the
> salaries of all employees. The data they received is a list of size n
> containing the tuples $\left\{s_{i\ },f_{i\ }\right\}_{i=1}^{n}$,
> where the number $s_i$ is the salary and the integer $f_i$ is the
> number of employees that got salary $s_i$ in the firm.
>
> Suggest an algorithm that gets the list as input and returns the
> median salary of the employees at the firm in time O(n) in the worst
> case, and justify why this is the running time of your algorithm. For
> example for the input (8000, 4),(20000, 1),(10000, 2) the output
> should be 8000 since the full, sorted list of salaries is: 8000, 8000,
> 8000, 8000, 10000, 10000, 20000. Remark: $\sum_{ }^{ }f_{i\ }$ (i.e.
> the number of employees) may be way bigger than n so you are not
> expected to write the expanded list of salaries.

Hi, I was given this question and was stuck on it for a while. It seems no matter what I try to do  I will exceed the $O(n)$ worst time restriction..
The direction I was going with is to somehow try to unzip the tuples into a list and use a simple run of $MedianOfMedians$ algorithm to find the median, but as the question states, we can't just create a single list of all salaries as the size of the new list will exceed $n$.
I feel like it has something to do with manipulation the values according to the total number of employees or maximum salary, etc, but no matter what kind of value manipulation I've tried it seems to fail.

I'm a bit lost as to how I am supposed to solve this, considering we've only learned very basic algorithms so far, such as selection and linear sorting algorithms in addition to some basic data strcuture such as trees, heaps, etc..

There is probably some trick involved which I am not getting, but what is it?

Comment: What is $n_i$ ?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I meant s_i

Comment: "we've [...] learned [...] linear sorting algorithms" - Which ones?

Comment: Please credit the original source of the problem.  That is what you are supposed to do. If it is a course, identify the course or the textbook or the instructor. (Furthermore, without that I would not upvote.)

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: @JohnL. Hi, this is a homework question from the Data Structures course I'm taking in my university. The authur is probably one of the professor's teaching assistants, who should I credit in this case?

Comment: @MathCurious Could you please raise a question on [the meta site](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com)? I am not certain what is the appropriate action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can still use the linear time selection algorithm (median of medians) here. Let's call this algorithm $Select$ and let the median position be $m$, which is initially equal to $n/2$.Recall that the algorithm has 3 phases:

1. Group by 5 and select median of each group
2. Choose partition element $p$, by applying $Select$ to find the median of the medians.
3. Partition the elements around $p$. If $p$ is the true median, return it otherwise recursively apply $Select$ to one side of the partition.

Observe first that it is possible that the frequency of each tuple is 1, which reduces the problem to the original median selection.

Below we describe $Select'$ a modification of $Select$ that allows values with frequencies greater than 1:

1. Group by 5 and select median of each group based only on the value, ignoring the frequency.
2. Choose $p$ by applying the $Select$ algorithm to find the median of the medians. Since the original  $Select$ algorithm is being used, the frequencies of the medians are not considered in the selection.
3. Partition the tuples around $p$. During the partition, sum-up the frequency of each tuple that ends up on the left side of $p$. Call this sum $l$. If $l \geq m$, recursively apply $Select'$ to the left partition. Else, if ($l + p.frequency) \geq m$, then $p$ is the median and we are done. Otherwise, update $m$ to  $m - (l+p.frequency)$ and recursively apply $Select', $ on the right partition.

The reason why we ignore the frequency on steps 1 and 2, is to guarantee that on step 3, the number of elements removed after partition is similar to what is expected from the original $Select$ algorithm. The additional step of accumulating the frequencies to get $l$, increases the running time of the partition step by a constant factor only, hence it has no significant effect on the asymptotic running-time of the algorithm. Therefore, the running-time of $Select'$ is also $O(n) $.

Comment: @JohnL., thanks for the clarification. I made an update, hopefully this makes the answer clearer.

Comment: This algorithm can just use $Select$ to find the median of the values (the $s_i$'s). There is no need to repeat the description of $Select$ as step 1 and 2 inside the description of $Select'$ again.

Comment: Where is the analysis of time-complexity?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what you mean when you say that the $Select$ can be used exactly as it is to find the median. I decided to include steps 1 and 2 in the modified version just to emphasize the importance of not considering the frequency in selecting the partition element, the reason for this is discussed in the last part of my answer.

Comment: As for the running-time, I was expecting it would be clear from my discussion that the changes have no significant effect on the running-time of the original selection algorithm. I would be open for suggestion as to what needs further clarification here. Thanks for all the suggestions, by the way.

Comment: The step1 and step 2 of $Select'$ can be replaced by one sentence, "Call $Select$ to find the index of the median of all *values*".

Comment: Or am I talking about a different algorithm than yours?

Comment: There is a possibility that there can be slight variations of this linear-time approach. In that case, it looks like my variation is clearer. (I still believe you meant my variation instead of "find the median of the medians". )

Comment: Even if my variation is clearer, your variation (if it does make sense) might be faster. I will write code to implement my variation.

Comment: I think we have a slightly different algorithm. The median of medians would be the median of the medians from each group. The median obtained here is not necessarily the true median of all elements, but only used as a partition element that would guarantee that a large enough number of elements will be discarded on each recusive call.

Comment: @Russel Thanks for your answer! It seems like exactly the algorithm they were aiming for in this question. Altough as I'm a novice to everything regarding time complexity analyzis  I'm having a hard time understanding why the additional step of summing the frequencies doesn't hurt the time complexity.. It might be clear but I'm having trouble understanding it..

Comment: From my understanding, as the median of medians guarantees a pivot that is larger than at most n/7 elements, in every step we are making additional n/7 calculations in the worst case, making the complexity t(n/5)+2t(n/7)+cn (correct me if I'm wrong), so you're saying that once I open it up I can prove that it's acctualy O(n)?

Comment: The cost for summing the frequency will be added to the $cn$ term, which represents the cost of the partition. It would not affect the recursive terms, that is why it retains the original running-time of $Select$. Recall that in partition we scan the entire array to find elements that must be placed on ther correct partition with respect to $p$. Now during this scan, when we find an element less than $p$, we add its frequency to $l$. This step will increase the time of each scan by a constant additive factor only, hence constant factor increase overall to the entire partition procedure.

Comment: Great, I understand now! Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If the pairs are given ordered by increasing salary, it suffices to compute the prefix sum of the frequencies $F_k:=\sum_{i=1}^k f_k$ and find the sum closest to the half of the total.

If the pairs are not ordered, you are stuck.

Comment: Does that mean that is it impossible to solve the problem in O(n) worst case time without sorting the salaries first?

Comment: @MathCurious: I don't see a way.